# Finding y(x) and extremals of functional with Euler equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I want to use the Euler equation to find $y=y(x)$ to get the extremals for the following functional: $$\int_a^b \left[xy + 2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right] \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I know that the Euler equation is given as
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = 0$$ but I am not sure how to apply it in this situation.

Is it even possible to find extremals without boundary conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Calling $L(y, y', x) = x y +2y'^2$ The Euler equation is

$$
L_y -(L_{y'})' = 4y''-x=0
$$

Solving for $y$ we have

$$
y = C_1+x C_2 +\frac{x^3}{24}
$$

The boundary conditions are fixed using the constants $C_1, C_2$